# Is Bluefish text editor compatible for Xfce(GKT2)?

Tags: compatibility, text-editor

I like Bluefish text editor but want to make sure it doesn't have a huge set of libraries that will swamp my small computer. I'm using Xubuntu 13.10.

Comment: ...I guess your question is mainly if Bluefish it is too heavy, rather than if it is compatible with XFce?

Comment: Yes, you're right, Jacob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to know what bluefish depends on and what it will install, search the application in synaptic and right click on it's name. In <kbd>Properties</kbd> you will see all dependencies and the size of the application.